# CSS z-index property doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, z-index

I'm trying to do input range with two sliders in my project. So I wrote the html something like this:

```css
.acCalcInputRange input[type="range"] {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.6rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

//for input thumb
.acCalcInputRange input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  pointer-events: all;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: none;
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="acCalcInputRange">
  <input type="range" class="form-range input-range" value="30000" id="customRange1" min="10000" max="90000" onchange="HomeInputChange()">
  <input type="range" class="form-range input-range" value="70000" id="customRange2" min="10000" max="90000" onchange="HomeInputChange()">
</div>
```

But one Thumb doesn't appear properly. I tried hard But unable to solve the issue. Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Edit:
Wanted to achieve this and perfectly got it on chrome
[image: Chrome image]

But in Firefox , got some issue:
[image: Firefox image]

Help me if you can!

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you want to achieve? At the moment the two input elements are both positioned relative to the bottom at the same y value and the second is understandably overwriting the first so the thumb looks as though it is behind, but it is in the right place (on top) of its own track.

Comment: I added two pictures. As my design in chrome , I want to achieve the same in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Both sliders have the same `z-index` value and as a result the second slider overlaps the first one.

The approach that your are following does not seem to be ideal for creating an input range with 2 sliders.

For a proper solution, please have a look at this codepen:
https://codepen.io/rendykstan/pen/VLqZGO

Comment: That link still doesn't work if you open it in Firefox because Firefox just doesn't support z-index on range inputs.